# Java/Web Service - How can I call function with params and get return data?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a WebService for communicating with MySQL database, things like:
SignUp(String username, String password) which returns 0 or 1 based if Sign Up was successful or not.

Web Service is hosted on local GlassFish server.
I have a java client, how can I call SignUp() function from java client to Web Service and get the return data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use wsimport against the WSDL to generate the client stubs and then from the client stubs just invoke the methods.

Comment: Sorry I am completely new to Web Services, could you explain in a bit more simple way?